# optimize table and query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a DB in MySQL Server, with information about ip range and location, it haves the next structure:

```
id (integer not null, auto inc)
from_ (bigint(20))
to_ (bigint(20))
region(integer)
```

The field region is a foreign key of a table cities (id, city_name).

As we know, to found to which country belongs an IP address, we have to execute something like the next query:

```
select region from ipcountry where ip >= from_ and ip <= to_
```

Due to the number of records, the query is too late for what I need.

Any idea to optimize this problem?

Comment: **ALWAYS** provide the **ACTUAL** schema generated with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, don't try to reproduce it by hands

Comment: What if you create 2 separate indexes: one for `from_` and one for `to_` and see if it works fast enough for your task?

Comment: this is the  SHOW CREATE TABLE CREATE TABLE `ipcountry` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `from_` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to_` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `region` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `FK_ipcountry_1` (`country`),
  KEY `FK_ipcountry_2` (`region`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ipcountry_2` FOREIGN KEY (`region`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ipcountry_3` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on `(from_, to_)`.  That is the place to start.

Then, the next idea is to have the index and change the query to:

```
select region
from ipcountry
where ip >= from_
order by from_ desc
limit 1;
```

If that doesn't give the performance boost, then you are going to have to think about how to optimize the data structure.  The extreme approach here is to list out all ip addresses with their region.  But, the billions of resulting rows may actually hinder performance.

If you go down this path, you need to be smarter.  One idea is to have separate tables for Type A, Type B, and Type C addresses which have constant regions.  Then a separate table for ranges of Type D addresses.

Comment: Composite index won't help for range comparisons, only the first column will be used

Comment: I don't understand why your query doesn't have "to_"

Comment: @Marichyasana . . . Correct.  It takes the first value after the `_from` -- sort of filling in the gaps if there were no match.  It is possible that adding `ip <= to_` would work fine, but there is a chance the index optimization would be off.

Comment: Thanks, I will test all your advices.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: the `to_` column of the index won't be used ever for this query anyway, why to include it?